# cfdocumentitem footer not displayed properly

Tags: css, coldfusion, cfdocument

I have a cfdocument being created. I have a a footer to it as below

```
    <cfdocumentitem type="footer" >

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="##FF6F00" >

<td align="right" style="font-size:10px">
 <font color="##FFFFFF">   &copy; AT&T Intellectual Property. All rights reserved.<br>AT&T and the AT&T logo are trademarks of AT&T Intellectual Property.</font>    
</td>
</table>
    </cfdocumentitem>
```

[image]

Im not able to get the orange body stretch out to the whole page, meaning the orange portion is being displayed as above. also the font size is not being rendered which I have specified. here is my style . Any ideas on what is wrong here?

```
.test{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:4px
}

.testone{align-content:stretch}
```

Comment: `CFDOCUMENT` and, by extension, `CFDOCUMENTITEM` uses only a portion of CSS available.  https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfdocument Unfortunately, `align-content` is not one of them. As for your font-size, don't forget the `;` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following changes:

- Set the left, right and top margins in your `<cfdocument>` tag to 0 and the *bottom* margin to the height of your footer
- Make sure the main part of your document has a `<body>` tag
- Add a `<style>` tag above the `<body>` tag and specify the main body margins, e.g. 2cm
- Now wrap your footer table in a `<body>` tag
- Add a `<style>` tag above this body tag *within*   the footer
- Set the body margin *and* padding to 0
- Set the table height to your `cfdocument marginBottom` value

Here's what your code should now look like (Note, I've specified cm as my unit):

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" marginBottom="1" marginLeft="0" marginRight="0" marginTop="0" unit="cm">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ margin:2cm; }
    </style>
    <body>
        <p>Page content</p>
    </body>
    <cfdocumentitem type="footer">
        <style type="text/css">
            body{ margin:0; padding:0; }
            table{ height:1cm; };
        </style>
        <body>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FF6F00" >
                <td align="right" style="font-size:10px">
                    <font color="#FFFFFF">
                        &copy; AT&T Intellectual Property. All rights reserved.
                        <br>AT&T and the AT&T logo are trademarks of AT&T Intellectual Property.
                    </font> 
                </td>
            </table>
        </body>
    </cfdocumentitem>
</cfdocument>
```

Answer (score 0):

To style a class you need to put a `.` before the atribute.

```
.test{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:4px;
}

.testone{align-content:stretch;}
```

Also make sure `cfdocumentitem` and `body` is 100% width.

Comment: yes i do have the . before the class, just updated it, it was a typo, still not working.... cfdocumentitem doesnot have a width attribute.